# Will oracle stored procedure support strcspn and strncpy inside the procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

Will oracle stored procedure support the use of 'strcspn' and 'strncpy' inside the procedure ?

Comment: Those aren't valid PL/SQL functions

Comment: You mean we cant use inside procedure block

Comment: Those are some kind of functions for character conversions? What is your requirement?

Comment: What function is that? Where did you get the information that those are valid PL/SQL functions?

Comment: As input parameter im going to pass Port and IP together like this "4000-10.1.1.1" and inside procedure i want to seperate the port and IP and the above function i mentioned ll do that.

Comment: If they're in the manual as valid functions, sure. (They're not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they are c functions not pl/sql. to get the IP + port from the string you've supplied its like this anonymous block sample

(sample code assumes there's a "-" in the string, you may want to validate this up front!)

```
declare
  v_str  varchar2(1000) := '4000-10.1.1.1';
  v_port pls_integer;
  v_ip   varchar2(50);
begin
  v_port := substr(v_str, 1, instr(v_str, '-')-1);
  v_ip   := substr(v_str, instr(v_str, '-') + 1);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_port);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_ip);
end;
/
```

Comment: substr(str, 1, instr(v_str, '-')-1);
in the above substr instead of str, v_str should be used right?

Comment: sorry yeah v_str. wrote that when travelling, without access to a db :)